# Decomposition of total Interaction energy with SAPT or EDA-NOCV

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I want to perform energy decomposition analysis for some Hydrogen bonded complexes. I came to know that ORCA and Psi4 allows EDA-NOCV an SAPT(0,2,3) respectively. But I do not know which one would be better, and how to perform them.

Comment: Although an answer to this question would be opinion-based, I recommend [an article that does both techniques and compares them](https://doi.org/10.1002/ejic.201701337). Hint: numbers are different but conclusions are rather consistent.

Comment: Although this is a personal opinion, SAPT0, especially F-SAPT(0) seems like a powerful tool for performing EDA and decomposing the energies for different functional groups.

Comment: @user3786990 could you share link?

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jctc.7b01053 is one example.

Answer (score 4):

SAPT(O) is an amazing tool for partitioning the interaction energies, it yields meaningful values and data. ETS-NOCV is also very good for partitioning the interaction energy, but it does it in a much different way, it yields values that correspond more to the orbital interactions, and more so the sigma and pi orbital mixing (although orca will not partition more than just the overall orbital mixing). ETS-NOCV is really good for giving qualitative orbital pictures for electron donation and back-donation. For hydrogen bonding, i'd suggest SAPT